# Re-defining a field in Serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

I am following the DRF tutorial, and there I faced the 'serializer'. Almost everything was easy to understand except for this one - when you redefine a field that's already in your connected(by model field in meta class).

Following is the serializer of the model 'user'

```
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(
        max_length = 128,
        min_length=8,
        write_only=True 
    )

    token = serializers.CharField(max_length=255, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

And the other code here, the corresponding model of the serializer above, 'User'

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(db_index=True, unique=True)

    #Here, the password field here!
    password = models.CharField(_('password'), max_length=128)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Now, you can see that in this tutorial, password is already in the model, but it's been redefined in the serializer... even if it uses the ModelSerializer, which can automatically imports all the field in the corresponding model.

Could you explain the reason why we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `User.password` is a django model field, while `RegistrationSerializer.password` is a serializer field.

From [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers), the purpose of the serializer in this case is to convert the model "to native Python datatypes that can then be easily rendered into JSON, XML or other content types".  As a bit of a simplification, think of the serializer as defining how things look on your API, while the model defines the interface to your database.  The serializer field defines how one model field is to be converted.  If your serializer inherits from DRF's [`ModelSerializer`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer), then DRF tries to infer how to serialize all the fields on that model *which do not already have a corresponding serializer field defined in your serializer class*.  So defining a field in the serializer **is not redefining** it, but telling DRF not to try to infer a specification.

In this case, the definition of the `password` serializer field adds a minimum length and tells the serializer that the field is to be write only.